# How to put an image from ImageField on an html email template in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have in `views.py`:

```
   def buy(request):
       if request.method=='POST':
           form=forms.Purchase(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               user = Person.objects.filter(first_name=form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')).filter(last_name=form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')).first()
               name=form.cleaned_data.get('first_name') + form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
               subject, from_email, to = 'Subject test1234', 'address@gmail.com', form.cleaned_data.get('email')
               html_content = render_to_string('tickets/mail_template.html', {'first_name':user.first_name, 'imagelink':user.qr_image})
               text_content = strip_tags(html_content)
               msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
               msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
               msg.send()
               return redirect('thankyou')
        else:
           form=forms.Purchase()

return render(request, 'tickets/buy.html', {'form': form})
```

Inside of the ImagField is contained jpg image file, and I want it to show on the html email being sent.

mail_template.html:

```
{% extends "event/base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        <p>{{ first_name }}</p>
        <img src= {{ imagelink }}>
    {% endblock content%}
```

The first_name works, but the image does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because django will store the url to the image in relative format. You have to make image src to be relative url so that your mail reader can be able to read the image src.

So to solve that, you could create absolute url using [HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri):

your `views.py`:

```
def view(request):

    imagelink = request.build_absolute_uri(user.qr_image.url)
    # ...{'first_name':user.first_name, 'imagelink': imagelink}
```

keep the rest as it is.

---

In some case you don't have request object then you could use settings to store `SERVER_URL` and you can combine `SERVER_URL` with `user.qr_image` to get the absolute url.

*settings.py*

```py
SERVER_URL="https://your-domain.com" # You could use django-environ to load this from environment variables also to be flexible when switching between environments
```

*views.py*

```
from django.conf import settings

def view(request):

    imagelink = settings.SERVER_URL + user.qr_image.url
    # ...{'first_name':user.first_name, 'imagelink': imagelink}
```

Comment: I tried this method and I got this error:

`'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'decode'`


What could this be? Could you explain the process of getting `SERVER_URL` through settings?

Comment: @LoganSchneider, just updated the answer. `ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'decode'` you've got this because `user.qr_image` won't return a url, change to `user.qr_image.url` to see the miracle :D..

Comment: Also, how would I set the SERVER_URL using django-environ? I looked at the documentation but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks :)

Comment: You should try that first. Just install it, set an environment variable named `SERVER_URL`, using `env = Environ()` to initiate an environ instance, then access the variable `env.str("SERVER_URL", default="default value")`, try that first and if you're facing with any issue, just let me know